# New Xcode 7.3: Swift NSDate extension with nullable convenience init crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, convenience-methods, xcode7.3

I have this NSDate extension with nullable init, which worked fine all the time, until I updated to newly released Xcode 7.3.

Now it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
extension NSDate
{
    convenience init?(dateString:String, formatString:String?)
    {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatString

        let newDate:NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

        if let newNewDate = newDate
        {
            self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:newNewDate)
            return
        }

        print("ERROR: Wrong format [\(formatString)] for date [\(dateString)]")
        return nil
    }
}

let d1 = NSDate(dateString: "2016-01-01 11:00:00", formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") // OK
let d2 = NSDate(dateString: "qq123", formatString: "qwe") // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Do you have any possible solution for this?
Cannot figure out - am I abusing extension of NSDate somehow?

Comment: If you call `self.init()` before `return nil` then it works

Comment: Thanks, this helped... although, I don't understand why, but at least it works now. (y)

Answer (score 1):

As [dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395203/dan) mentioned in his comment already, making sure to always initialize the object before returning `nil` from a failable initializer (or throwing from a throwing initializer) fixes this issue.

For more information on the underlying issue, see [SR-704: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on returning nil from a failable initializer of NSObject subclass](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-704). Looks like it was fixed in the mainline branch, but didn’t make it into the final Swift 2.2 release. Expect it to be fixed in the next point update.